# How can I cast GridView to table in pdf with additional columns and custom layout

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, itext

I have a class that extends IPdfPageEvent named ImportExport. There is a static method in this class:

```
public static void ExportToPDF(GridView gv, string Title, string Filter, int[] ColToRmove, string PaperType, bool PrepareExport)
    {
        //Removes all controls from GridView 
        if (PrepareExport == true)
            PrepareForExport(gv);
   
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
        if (ColToRmove != null)
        {
            int i = 0;
            foreach (int a in ColToRmove)
            {

                if (i == 0)
                {
                    gv.Columns[a].Visible = false;
                    gv.Columns.RemoveAt(a);
                    gv.HeaderRow.Cells.RemoveAt(a);
                }
                else
                {
                    gv.Columns[a - i].Visible = false;
                    gv.Columns.RemoveAt(a - i);
                    gv.HeaderRow.Cells.RemoveAt(a - i);
                }
                i = i + 1;
            }
        }
        // Adds column which represents stores row number.
        BoundField field = new BoundField();
        field.HeaderText = "SrNo.";
        gv.Columns.Insert(0, field);
        foreach (GridViewRow row in gv.Rows)
        {
            TableCell cl = new TableCell();
            if (gv.Rows[row.RowIndex].Cells[0].Text != "Total:")
                cl.Text = Convert.ToString(row.RowIndex + 1);

            cl.Width = Unit.Pixel(20);
            cl.Attributes.Add("style", "color:#000");
            row.Cells.AddAt(0, cl);
        }

        gv.HeaderRow.Visible = false;
        gv.RenderControl(hw);

        StringBuilder strbldr = new StringBuilder();
        //Static field, stores html header of whole document. Logo for now.
        strHeder = new StringBuilder();
        //Static field, stores html header of page, title, date of creation and table header row.
        strFilter = new StringBuilder();

        strHeder.Append("<div><table style='text-align: center; line-height:12px;' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'><tr ><td style='vertical-align: top;'><img src='"
            + HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~\\images\\logo.png")
            + "' width='150px'; height ='50px'/></td><td colspan='7' style='font-size: 13px;  font-weight: bold; text-align: center; vertical-align: top;'> <br />"
           + "</td></tr></table>");

        strFilter.Append("<table style='text-align: center; line-height:12px;' cellpadding='1' cellspacing='0'><tr bgcolor='#eeeeee'><td style='font-size: 10px;  text-align:left; vertical-align: top; font-weight:bold' >" + Title + "</td><td style='font-size: 8px;  text-align:right; vertical-align: top; font-weight:bold' >Print Data: " + System.DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") + "</td></tr><tr><td style='font-size: 10px;font-weight: bold;  text-align:left; vertical-align: top;' colspan='2' bgcolor='#eeeeee'>" + Filter + " </td></tr></table>");
        strFilter.Append("<table border='1' style='font-size:9px;'>");
        strFilter.Append("<tr bgcolor='rgb(49,49,49)' color='#fff' style='width:20px !important'>");

        for (int i = 0; i < gv.Columns.Count; i++)
        {
            strFilter.Append("<th style='width:20px !important'>");

            strFilter.Append(gv.Columns[i].ToString());
            strFilter.Append("</th>");
        }

        if (gv.Columns.Count == 1)
        {
            for (int c = 0; c < gv.HeaderRow.Cells.Count; c++)
            {
                strFilter.Append("<th style='width:20px !important'>");
                strFilter.Append(gv.HeaderRow.Cells[c].Text.ToString());
                strFilter.Append("</th>");
            }
        }

        strFilter.Append("</tr>");
        strFilter.Append("</table>");

        strbldr.Append("<div style='font-size:9px;margin-top:10px;'>");

        strbldr.Append(sw.ToString());
        strbldr.Append("</div>");

        StringReader sr = new StringReader(strbldr.ToString());
        Document document = new Document();

        strPaperType = PaperType.ToUpper();
        Image image = Image.GetInstance(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~\\images\\logo.png"));
        image.Alignment = Image.UNDERLYING;
        image.ScalePercent(80);

        if (PaperType.ToUpper() == "P")
        {
            document = new Document(PageSize.A4_LANDSCAPE, 10f, 10f, 10f, 0f);
            image.SetAbsolutePosition(120f, 300f);
        }
        else if (PaperType.ToUpper() == "LS")
        {
            document = new Document(PageSize.LEGAL_LANDSCAPE, 10f, 10f, 10f, 0f);
            document.SetPageSize(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.LEGAL_LANDSCAPE.Rotate());
            image.SetAbsolutePosition(275f, 100f);
        }
        else
        {
            document = new Document(new Rectangle(288f, 144f), 10, 10, 10, 10);
            document.SetPageSize(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.A4.Rotate());
            image.SetAbsolutePosition(275f, 100f);
        }

        HTMLWorker htmlWorker = new HTMLWorker(document);
        PdfWriter pdfDoc = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, HttpContext.Current.Response.OutputStream);
        pdfDoc.PageEvent = new ImportExport();
        document.Open();
        htmlWorker.Parse(sr);
        document.Close();

        HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "inline;filename=" + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString() + ".pdf");
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
    }
```

Regardless of not the best coding style, it worked well for every page. It generated table with equally devided columns  Now for one of the pages we need to add another column named discription and reduce or make bigger some of the columns so it could fit better.

So first of all I implented XMLParser. It made table look like GridView where data was taken from. Then I tryied several different ways to set your custom css, through CssResolver class and through CssClass property.

```
ICSSResolver cssResolver = XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().GetDefaultCssResolver(false);
cssResolver.AddCssFile(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/assets/css/table.css"), true);
```

```
 gv.CssClass = "table-import";
```

After this I've tryied to build my GridView with data from method GridView parametr but that was not a good idea neither due to generic logic removing. How expected result can be done and if it could be done at all?